# Find and insert - std::map c++

Tags: c++

I have problem with my code. How can I fix it? text param is const string.

```
 'std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, unsigned int>' is not derived from 'const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>'
 { return *__it == _M_value; }
```

.h file:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, uint32_t> MessageDataList;
MessageDataList messages;
```

.cpp file:

```
MessageDataList::const_iterator mit = std::find(messages.begin(), messages.end(), text.c_str());
if (mit == messages.end())
    messages.insert(std::make_pair(text.c_str(), 1));
else
{}
```

Comment: why are you using `.c_str()`?

Comment: I cant compile this, getting this error: 'std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, unsigned int>' is not derived from 'const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>'

Comment: Yes, you said that bit already.

Comment: Instead of `text.c_str()` you have to use `text` itself. Also you have used `messages.begin()` and later you expected return Iterator as a `const_Iterator`

Comment: I've already fixed problem with @YSC help.

Answer (score 2):

With `std::map`, you should use [`std::map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) instead of `std::find`:

```
MessageDataList::const_iterator mit = messages.find(text);
```

---

Unrelated suggestion, using C++17's [`std::as_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const) to automatically call `find` from a const reference, which returns a `const_iterator` and enables `auto` to infer it:

```
auto mit = std::as_const(messages).find(text);
```

Comment: @k.k. if that's true, please accept my answer by clicking the checkmark bellow the answer's score.